# Where do coins primarily enter circulation?

Tags: cash, coins

I’m in the UK but would also be interested in answers about other countries.

When newly minted coins enter circulation (here in the UK it’s via dedicated Cash Centres), what % go to different types of business?

Is it still mostly banks or something else?

Basically, if numbers were added to the flows at the bottom of this infographic, what would they be?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how the coins are being distributed? Through banks.

Comment: I thought that was the case, but then I went looking on the Royal Mint website and they include banks under other end-user businesses, not as anything special. https://www.royalmint.com/corporate/circulating-coin/uk-currency/uk-cash-centres/

Comment: Don't know about the UK in particular, but generally speaking, coins and paper money goes to whoever orders it - which is banks, since they generally don't give accounts to random people, since they assume random people get their coins and paper money from their banks.

Comment: The banks, obviously, have to pay for the coins and paper money they order. Not just the printing cost, but they also have to pay the money itself, so that money doesn't get created or destroyed this way.